Equivalent characterization of the support of a distribution in $C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$.
Before presenting my question in a formal way, I should present some contextualization so my problem is well understood.
Contextualization. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a non-empty open set and consider the usual space of distributions $C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$ (i.e., the dual space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $\Omega$). We have the following introductory definitions:
Definition 1. Let $\omega$ be a non-empty open set such that $\omega \subset \Omega$ and consider a distribution $T \in C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$. The restriction of $T$ to $\omega$ is the distribution $T|_{\omega} \in C_0^\infty {'} (\omega)$ given by
$$ \langle T|_\omega, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, \widetilde{\varphi} \rangle,  \quad \varphi \in C_0^\infty(\omega),$$
where $\widetilde{\varphi}$ is the extension by zero of $\varphi$ to $\Omega$.
Definition 2. An open set $A \subset \Omega$ is said an open annihilation set of the distribution $T \in C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$ if $T|_A = \hat 0$ (here, $\hat 0$ stands for the zero distribution in $C_0^\infty {'} (A)).$
Definition 3. We define the support of a distribution $T \in C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$ as
$$ \text{supp } T := \{ x \in \overline{\Omega} : T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r)} \neq \hat{0}, \, \forall r > 0 \} $$
(note that here $\hat{0}$ represents the zero distribution in $C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega \cap B(x,r))$).
My question. Now, I am trying to prove that an equivalent characterization of the support of a distribution is given by the following: for any distribution $T \in C_0^\infty {'} (\Omega)$, there holds
$$ \text{supp } T = \text{ complement of the biggest open annihilation set of }T, $$
where the biggest open annihilation set of $T$ is simply the union of all the open annihilation sets of $T$.
My attempt. I began by analyzing the inclusion $(\subset)$. Consider a point $x \in \text{supp } T$, that is, $x \in \overline \Omega$ is such that $T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r)} \neq 0$, for all $r > 0$. Additionally, suppose that $x$ belongs to the biggest open annihilation set of $T$ (which I will denote from now on with the letter $A$). Obviously, my goal here is to reach a contradiction. Now, since $A$ is open and $x \in A$, we know that there exists some $r_0 > 0$ such that $B(x,r_0) \subset A$. Moreover, let us now analyze the distribution $(T|_A)|_{B(x,r_0)}.$ It is clear that
$$ \langle (T|_A)|_{B(x,r_0)}, \varphi \rangle = \langle T|_A, \widetilde \varphi \rangle = 0, \quad \varphi \in C_0^\infty(B(x,r_0),  $$
where $\widetilde \varphi$ denotes the extension by zero of $\varphi$ to $A$ and the last equality follows since $A$ is an open annihilation set of $T$. This means that $(T|_A)|_{B(x,r_0)}$ is the zero distribution in $C_0^\infty {'} (B(x,r_0)$. Now, since $x \in \text{supp } T$, we know that, in particular,
$$ T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r_0)} \neq \hat 0. $$
Let us now guarantee that $T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r_0)} = (T|_A)|_{B(x,r_0)}$, which is obviously a contradiction according to our two latest conclusions. Since $B(x,r_0) \subset A \subset \Omega$, it is clear that $T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r_0)} = T|_{B(x,r_0)}.$ Furthermore, using the definition of restriction fo a distribution, it is trivial to check that
$$ T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r_0)} = T|_{B(x,r_0)} = (T|_A)|_{B(x,r_0)}, $$
which is an obvious contradiction with our two precendet conclusion, finishing this inclusion.
$(\supset)$ This is being the problematic inclusion for me and where I need some kind of hint to advance further.
Thanks for any help in advance.

The fact that $\operatorname{supp} T$ is defined in $\overline{\Omega}$ rather than just $\Omega$ throws a wrench in your plans, as the complement in $\overline{\Omega}$ of the biggest annihilator set will contain all of $\partial \Omega$, which you don't want for your definition of support of a distribution if $T = \hat{0}$ on $\Omega$ for example.
Let's prove a slightly modified result:
$$\operatorname{supp} T \cap \Omega = \Omega \setminus U_T$$
for $U_T$ the biggest annihilator set of $T$ in $\Omega$.
We have:
$$\begin{split} \Omega \setminus (\operatorname{supp} T \cap \Omega) &= \Omega \setminus \left\{x \in \Omega \mid \forall r > 0,\, T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r)} \neq \hat{0}\right\}\\
&= \Omega \setminus \bigcap_{r > 0} \left\{x \in \Omega \mid T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r)} \neq \hat{0}\right\}\\
&= \bigcup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0 \atop T|_{\Omega \cap B(x,r)} = \hat{0}} \Omega \cap B(x,r)\\
&= \bigcup_{\omega \subset \Omega \atop T|_\omega = \hat{0}} \omega = U_T\end{split}$$
where the last line uses the facts that every open set is a union of open balls and that the property $T|_{\omega} = \hat{0}$ is transferred through union.
